# if statement calculation being shown in the wrong place

Tags: javascript, velo

I am a beginner and I have an if statement that is returning the input value in the text box that I want the calculation to be in, and returning the calculation in the text box where I originally input the information.

diagram of problem

[image]

```
$w.onReady(function () {
  $w("#generatequote").onClick((event) => {
    var SR = Number($w("#SR").value);
    if (SR<100) {
      $w("#SR").value = SR*2
    //if the input number is less than 100 display the input number times two
    }
    $w("#quotetext").value =(SR)
    });
```

This is a different way I tried but then it displays the input value without making the calculation

```
    var SR = Number($w("#SR").value);
    if (SR<100) {
        $w("#SR").value = ("#SR")*2
```

This is another way I tried but it also doesn't make the calculation

```
    var SR = Number($w("#SR").value);
    if (SR<100) {
        $w("#SR").value *2
    }
```

Comment: You want it in the text box or input?

Comment: I want the calculation displayed in the text box

Comment: Is the id of that textbox is `SR`. and tell if there is any element with id `SR`?

Comment: the id of the textbox is "quotetext". The element where the user inputs a value is defined as SR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, the only problem with your first code seems to be that you mixed up the two text-boxes.

`"#SR"` is the input box, and you are giving it a value of `SR*2`.

```
$w("#SR").value = SR*2
```

While `"#quotetext"` is where you want to display the result, but you are giving it a value of `SR`.

```
$w("#quotetext").value =(SR)
```

So, try flipping it around?

```
$w.onReady(function () {
  $w("#generatequote").onClick((event) => {
    var SR = Number($w("#SR").value);
    if (SR<100) {
      $w("#quotetext").value = SR*2
    //if the input number is less than 100 display the input number times two
    }
    $w("#SR").value =(SR)
    });
```